# PHP function to create slideshow

Tags: php, jquery, html, slideshow

I am currently using a PHP function to create a slideshow pulling images from a database.

I also want to use one of those images in a homepage slideshow - but only want an image to be pulled if the item itself in the database is tagged with a "feature" tag - How do I need to create a function to do this? Here is my tagged function and my slideshow function:

```
if(strtolower($term) == 'feature') {
    $query = "select * FROM $table WHERE (tags LIKE '%feature%') ORDER BY rid DESC LIMIT 5";
}
```

In a separate PHP functions file -

```
if (trim(mysql_result($this->result,0,"imageCarousel1") != '')) {
    $this->hassliderimage1 = true;
} else {
    $this->hassliderimage1 = false;
}

public function show_image_carousel1() {
    echo ('<img class="img-responsive" src="'.$this->directory.mysql_result($this->result,0,"imageCarousel1").'" />');
}
```

And then the slideshow is displayed on a page with:

```
<div>
<?php if ($recipe->hassliderimage1 == true) { 
        $recipe->show_image_carousel1();
} ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have gone by the following approach.

First, create a slideshow in plain HTML, CSS from some static data in javascript array. Test if it works as per your requirement [slideshow with one image in homepage sideshow]

Now the next part is replacing the static data with dynamic data from database using php, and send the data as a JSON response. Accept this JSON response and use JSON.parseJSON(data) to convert to javascript object.

Now, the next part is about the business logic in creating the dynamic data in PHP:

1. Only want an image to be pulled if the item itself in the database is tagged with a "feature" tag

   $query = "select * FROM $table WHERE tags LIKE '%feature%' ORDER BY rid DESC LIMIT 5";
2. To use one of those images in a homepage slideshow

   mark your special image with some extra data and identify it while you inject the data to your slideshow,

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what I ended up doing... was making a "search" for each tag - ie slide1, slide2, slide3, slide4, slide5 for the slideshow - and the database will have these tags in it - here is the php search I used for it.

```
      <?php if ($searchTerm != '') { ?>
          <?php 
              $result = searchRecipes('slide1','');
              while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                if($row['imageCarousel1'] != '') { 
                  $slide1 = '<img class="active" alt="slide1" src="/images/recipes/'.$row['imageCarousel1'].'" />';
                } 

              ?>
```

And then placed the image in it's place according to slide position in the html - so i have 5 php searches for 5 slides...might not be the best thing though I guess.

```
    <a href="recipe_display.php?r=<?=$row['rid'];?>"><?=$slide1;?></a>
  <div class="carousel-caption">
     <a href="recipe_display.php?r=<?=$row['rid'];?>"><h4><?=$row['name'];?></h4></a>
  </div>
```